# How to restart ExPex numbering from a specific point in the document?

Tags: numbering, linguistics, expex

I'm currently working on my linguistics thesis, and I would like to add several example texts into the appendix. So I would like the ExPex numbering to restart from the beginning of every different text from (1). Is that achievable with ExPex?

Main document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tipa} % IPA symbols. 
\usepackage{expex} % glossing

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle

%expex
\lingset{glhangindent=0em} % adjust as necessary
\lingset{numoffset=0.5cm} % indentation for examples in expex
%\lingset{aboveexskip=0pt} % spacing between exs
\lingset{aboveglftskip=-0.3pt} %spacing before glft

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\include{Chapter1/chapter1}
\include{Chapter2/chapter2}

\appendix
\include{AppendixA/appendixa}

\backmatter
\end{document}
```

I have examples in each chapter and they are numbered from (1) until whatever, and now I would like the texts in the appendix number from (1) for each text (Text 1 and Text 2). Appendix:

```
\chapter{Example texts}
\section{Text 1}
\ex Line 1 \xe
\ex Line 2 \xe

\section{Text 2}
\ex Line 1 \xe
\ex Line 2 \xe
```

Comment: Could you please show us a MWE ? http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe

Comment: look here : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters

Comment: The example you've posted isn't really a minimal example for your question. The full document doesn't have any example (`\ex ... \xe`) code, has more structure than is needed and uses `\include`, which doesn't help since we don't have your included files (and they are not necessary in this case). See my answer for a more perspicuous MWE for this question.

Answer (score 5):

The ExPex package uses its own counter/reference system which is quite powerful but somewhat idiosyncratic. It's also usable with the regular LaTeX `\label` and `\ref` system but without the extra functionality of its built-in system.

The main counter used by ExPex is `\excnt` but this is a TeX count register and not a LaTeX counter, so it cannot be set and reset using the regular LaTeX methods.  Instead, you set it directly by using the TeX syntax `\excnt=1`.

If you want example numbers to start at 1 for each chapter automatically you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{expex}
% Restart numbering each chapter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\excnt=1}{}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\ex An example \xe
\ex An example \xe
\chapter{Bar}
\ex An example \xe
\ex An example \xe
\appendix
% If numbering is to restart only here, put the \pretocmd line here
\chapter{Appendix}
\ex An example \xe
\ex An example \xe
\end{document}
```

If you only want to restart for the appendices, then you can put the `\pretocmd` line right after the `\appendix` command in your document.

Answer (score 0):

how to set a counter :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}
\section{test1}
\label{sec:test1}

\section{test2}
\label{sec:test2}


\setcounter{section}{10}
\section{test3}
\label{sec:test3}

\section{test4}
\label{sec:test4}

\section{test5}
\label{sec:test6}

\section{test6}
\label{sec:test6}


\end{document}
```

1 test1

2 test2

11 test3

12 test4

13 test5

14 test6

Comment: Thank you very much, the counter I wanted to set is the number of linguistic examples inside expex, not the number of the section... and I still haven't figured out how to do that after reading that wiki page :(

Comment: Look in the package documentation : http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/plain/contrib/expex/expex-doc.pdf you have some counters.

Comment: Many thanks, it turned out that I just needed to set `\excnt=1` at the place where I want to reset... :)

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. ExPex doesn't use regular LaTeX counters, so you can't set and reset them with regular LaTeX methods. I don't want to discourage you from answering, but if a question is about a specific package, and you're not familiar with it, perhaps you should think twice before you answer, or at least test your answer with the package loaded.

Comment: @AlanMunn thanks for your advice, I will take care the next time. Do I have to delete my answer ?