# How to adjust space between interlinear lines

Tags: vertical-alignment, expex

How do you adjust the vertical space between the interlinear lines in `expex`?

Specifically, I would like to **reduce** the vertical space between `gla` and `glb`, and between `glb` and `glc`. I have highlighted the space I am talking about in the figure below. I would like to make that space smaller.
[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{FrankRuehl}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Corbel}

\lingset{
    everygla=\large,
    everyglb=\scriptsize\englishfont,
    everyglc=\scriptsize\englishfont,
    glwordalign=center
}

\begin{document}
\begingl
  \gla שלום {קוראים לי} דוד //
  \glb shalom \textenglish{korim li}  david //
  \glc Hello \textenglish{my name is} David //
\endgl

\end{document}
```

Comment: Lingset: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/288135/124842 and lingstyle: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203018/124842

Comment: As a side note, you can avoid using `\textenglish{}` in the gloss lines by adding `\beginL` to your `everyglb` and `everyglc` definitions. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292391/42880).

Comment: this is not specific to the package you're using, but it looks to me like the distance between the lines is the same.  the distance is usually measured from baseline to baseline, and for the hebrew, the baseline is the line that would be drawn immediately below all the letters except for the one with depth (compare this to the descender on the "y" in the third line).  so you're asking for uneven spacing.  i don't know whether any letters with descenders might appear in the transliterated line (line 2), but if they do, then the distinction would be more obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should adjust the values of `aboveglbskip` and `aboveglcskip`. According to p. 38 of the [`expex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/expex/expex-doc.pdf), the default value for both of these is `0pt` but you can specify a negative value to make the lines more condensed. You can specify these values in all the usual places (as an optional argument to a gloss environment or example environment, in a `lingstyle` that is called within the gloss/example, or globally in `\lingset`).